# Usar texto como input

Tags: html, css

Deseo hacer un botón de compra, con algunos atributos CSS, pero sin usar imágenes.

Quiero que sea un cuadrado negro, con el texto `COMPRAR` en letras blancas.

Esto es lo que intenté hasta ahora, pero no queda en negro y no se parece a un botón de esta forma.

```html
<input 
  style="border:1px solid black; padding:5px; width:100%; height:30px; margin-top:15px;"
  type="image"
  border="0"
  name="submit"
  alt="PURCHASE">
```

¿Es esto posible?

Comment: No me queda claro cuál es el problema o el comportamiento deseado.

Comment: @Ivan Modifiqué el texto de la pregunta para que quede más claro lo que estás preguntando. Si hay algo que no esté bien, no dudes en modificarlo/comentarlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si es que es lo que entiendo, tu deseas simplemente añadir un estilo CSS al botón de comprar. Tendrías que leer más acerca de CSS y aprender a usarlo. Te dejo un manual haciendo [clic aquí](https://librosweb.es/libro/css/).

```css
.purchase{
    background-color:#000;
    color:#FFF;
    border:transparent;
    padding:5px 10px;
    cursor:pointer;
  }
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="Comprar" class="purchase">
```

Comment: Sí ! Gracias Vaca!

Answer (score -2):

Usar el atributo placeholder="tu mensaje" o si querés un valor inicial podes usar value="tu valor"

El atributo value, es el que va a viajar a tu servidor. O sea lo que ingresa tu usuario.
El placeholder, es para mostrar un texto y al momento de ingresar un valor desaparece, está pensado para eliminar o no abusar mucho de los label.

No tiene sentido que uses los dos juntos.

Comment: Hola Leonardo, gracias por responder, pero no es así lo que quiero, es un botón de "Pagar" donde se confirman otros atributos ya fijados en inputs anteriores.. este solo debería hacer el Submit, no sé si me explico...

Comment: @IvanSoler la verdad es que eso no se entiende muy bien y dista mucho de lo que pone en el texto de la pregunta. Por favor, edítala para aclarar más lo que estás buscando.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro a ver si ahora está mejor

Comment: Creo que logro entender el requerimiento.

Comment: Podrías disparar el submit directamente con jQuery

Comment: Entonces ahí lo podes ejecutar desde una imagen, un div, un button

Comment: <form id="target" action="destination.html">
  <input type="text" value="Hello there">
  <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
<div id="other">
  Trigger the handler
</div>

$( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {
  alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
  event.preventDefault();
});

fuente: https://api.jquery.com/submit/